# cronjob to execute a list of urls using curl which has been pulled from a databse

Tags: php, curl, cron

I am wanting to create a cron job that execute form data that is pulled from the database

The php file will print this form for all the entries in my database, how do i get cron to auto submit these forms?

```
<form action="/link.php?a=addurl" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="urls" value="VALUEFROMDATABASE"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

my knowledge is hmmm.... very basic sorry in advance

Basically what i am trying to achieve here, is that i have urls stored in another table and need this cron job to submit the data to the form as it will pull information regarding the domain and store it in my database

I have tried basic url's with trying to post the value in the url but failed, and tried to look into other methods.

Comment: Form is executed on client-side interaction. Cronjob is server-side. **And never shall the twain meet,** unless you make special complicated arrangements. I'm sure that if you write here what you're trying to achieve, you'll get a better/realistic solution.

Comment: ill up date my question, :)

Comment: OK. You clearly don't understand what client-side and server-side means. You need to stop and go learn how PHP actually works and that it can't interact with your browser view of the page without JS programming and Ajax. PHP does not work as you think. When you see the page in your browser, the PHP instance that produced it is CLOSED.